# Timeout while trying to upload a file from storage to an FTP server passing by a cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, ftp, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am actually encountering a problem while I am trying to upload a file from storage to an FTP server, passing by a triggered node js function.

So, every time a file, with a specific name, is uploaded to Firebase storage, this file should automatically be uploaded to the FTP server.
To do that, I am using [promise-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-ftp). 
I am able to connect to the server but when it comes to upload files, I am faced with a connection timeout. I tried with another node package. Same issues.

But, when I execute the js script locally without passing by a trigger, the file is successfully uploaded.

My promise-ftp script that I tried locally looks like :

```
function test() {
  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), '123.pdf');
  ftp.connect({host: 'ftp.aaa-bbbb.ccc', user: 'aaabbb', password: 'pswd123'})
  .then(function (serverMessage) {
    console.log(serverMessage);
    return ftp.put(tempFilePath, 'local.pdf');
  })
  .then(function () {
    return ftp.end();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Ready to delete");
     // Once the pdf has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
  });
}
```

The node js could function use the same code but the file name and the destination name are different.

Any idea?

**UPDATE #1**

```
exports.updateToFTP = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {
    // [START eventAttributes]
    const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
    const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
    const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
    const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
    const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.
    // [END eventAttributes]

  // [START stopConditions]
  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  if (resourceState === 'exists') {
    // ignore for deletions
    return
  }
  if (!contentType.startsWith('application/pdf')) {
    return null;
  }
  // [END stopConditions]
  // Get the file name.
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  // get file from bucket.
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  var ftp = new PromiseFtp();
  return bucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath,
  }).then(() => {
    return ftp.connect({host: 'host', user: 'usr', password: 'pwd'})
  }).then(function (serverMessage) {
    console.log(serverMessage);
    return ftp.put(tempFilePath, fileName);
  }).then(function () {
    return ftp.end();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Ready to delete");
     // Once the pdf has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
    fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("Catching error");
      console.log(err)
  });
})
```

The error : (with ftp package only)

```
Timed out while making data connection
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/user_code/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:901:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

Random error with promise ftp (Can't reproduce it locally) :

```
ReferenceError: reentry is not defined
    at /user_code/node_modules/promise-ftp/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:937:18
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/user_code/node_modules/promise-ftp/node_modules/@icetee/ftp/lib/connection.js:962:9)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
```

*Maybe this is a bad practice to upload file from storage to FTP...*

Comment: Did you try to `catch` any errors on your chain? Have you tried logging at every stage? What does the log say?

Comment: I added a `catch` and isn't actually called.

Comment: And the logging I suggested?

Comment: Question updated with the error.

Comment: What payment plan is your Firebase project on?

Comment: I have the Flame plan (25$/month)

Comment: I added a random error to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You may have run into a limit on the outbound networking for the Flame plan (5 GB per month).  You can upgrade to the Blaze plan for pay-per-use unlimited networking.

Comment: Strange, because yesterday, the function has successfully sent a part of the file (so it was corrupted) and since, I can’t reproduce it and make it “works” again.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken about the Flame plan - it does have outbound networking, but it's limited.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase functions have time limit, so if your file size is large or you have a network delay which as a result increase the file transfer time, the function will timeout.

Here is the link to the limits firebase has specified: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits

You can use trigger to call a webhook with the stoage file downloadable url if the file size is very large and pull file to your server.

Comment: The file is really small ~= 650ko.

Comment: then your solution will work after applying solution @Doug provided in his answer.

Comment: Is there any official doc ? So I can ask my customer to upgrade the plan according to this information.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the question mark next to Cloud Functions in the billing page.  https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of hours I saw the commits on @icetee I found this. So all you have to do is:

1. go to node_modules\promise-ftp\node_modules@icetee\ftp\lib\connection.js
2. look for `this._send(pasvCmd, function(err, text) {`
3. replace for `this._send(pasvCmd, function reentry(err, text) {`

I dont know why this error keep on actual version